# Column not found when seeding database with structs with has_many relationship

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I first tried seeding my database with a simple one level deep structs and it works great. However, when I add in a Path mapping to match my top level structs paths field then I get the error.

```
 ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column "apis_id" of relation "paths" does not exist
```

I've tried removing the apis_id but I believe I need that field to preload the Path struct in my ApiController. Perhaps the problem lies in my `has_many`/`belongs_to` syntax although I believe I have it correct and I've tried swamping out other foreign_keys and references with no luck.

I could also be just missing something really stupid and need some fresh eyes, but I'm hoping my understanding of this relationship is possibly messed up.

Here are my migrations:

_create_api.exs

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateApi do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:apis) do
      add :basePath, :string
      add :definitions, :string
      add :paths, references(:paths)

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

_create_paths.exs

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreatePath do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:paths) do
      add :apis_id, :string
      add :route, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

My models:
api.ex

```
defmodule App.Api do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "apis" do
    field :basePath, :string
    field :definitions, :string
    has_many :paths, App.Path, foreign_key: :apis_id

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

path.ex

```
defmodule App.Path do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "paths" do
    belongs_to :apis, App.Api, references: :apis_id
    field :route, :string

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Also here is my ApiController api_controller.ex

```
defmodule App.ApiController do
  use App.Web, :controller

  alias App.Api

  def index(conn, _params) do
    apis = Repo.all(Api) |> Repo.preload([:paths])
    render conn, "index.json", apis: apis
  end
end
```

And finally my seeds.ex

```
alias App.Repo
alias App.Path
alias App.Api

api = %Api{
  basePath: "v1",
  definitions: "none",
  paths: [
    %Path{
      apis_id: 1,
      route: "/account"
    }
  ]
}

Repo.insert! api
```

This works if I rip out the %Path mapping and make it an empty string.

Any help of steering in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the column `apis_id` exist in your `paths` table? You can check by running `\d paths` in `psql`. It looks like you either forgot to run the migration or you edited a migration and didn't re-run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put reference to `paths` into the database. The relation one-to-many is just one sided - you just need `api_id` inside the `Path` schema, you don't need it the other way around.

However `Ecto` is able to map `Path`s into the field inside `Api` struct. What you don't need is the field `paths` inside `_create_api` migration.

So I believe the correct file contents should be:

`_create_api.exs`

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateApi do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:apis) do
      add :basePath, :string
      add :definitions, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

`_create_paths.exs`

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreatePath do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:paths) do
      add :api_id, references(:apis)
      add :route, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

`api.ex`

```
defmodule App.Api do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "apis" do
    field :basePath, :string
    field :definitions, :string
    has_many :paths, App.Path

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

`path.ex`

```
defmodule App.Path do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "paths" do
    belongs_to :api, App.Api
    field :route, :string

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Please note that I removed `references` and `foreign_key` from models. Also I changed the name of the field `apis_id` to `api_id` to match the standard naming.

**EDIT:** added seeds.exs

```
alias App.Repo
alias App.Path
alias App.Api

api = Repo.insert! %Api{
      basePath: "v1",
      definitions: "none"
    }

path = Repo.insert! %Path{
      api_id: api.id,
      route: "/account"
    }
```

But I advise you to use changesets.

Comment: Am I suppose to manually add in the `api_id` when creating my `Path` struct within `seeds.ex`? When I remove the addition of `api_id` I get this error: `** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * unique: paths_pkey

If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.`

Comment: the best way to insert stuff into the database is to just insert them one by one, so the Api schema first and then insert Path but with api_id - you can get it because you already inserted Api (or you can just pass whole struct like `path.api = api`) - please see my edit